# Dynamics CRM 365 sever-side synchronization enable http

Tags: smtp, dynamics-crm-365, server-side-sync

Hello I am running crm 365 on premise (9.1). Is there any trick anyone knows that can allow crm to use an smtp server via http? This is for server-side synchronization.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute the following queries:

```
 --UPDATE dbo.DeploymentProperties
  --SET BitColumn = 1
  --WHERE ColumnName in ('AllowCredentialsEntryViaInsecureChannels', 'ECAllowNonSSLEmail')
```

and then :

```
--UPDATE organizationbase
--SET featureset = '<features><feature xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><name>FCB.SHAREPOINTS2S</name><value>true</value><location>Organization</location><lastupdate>2019-10-01T04:57:53.8003027Z</lastupdate></feature><feature xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><name>FCB.USEMAILKITSMTPPROVIDERFOROUTGOINGEMAIL</name><value>false</value><location>Organization</location><lastupdate>2022-03-09T02:32:25.6600124Z</lastupdate></feature></features>'
--Where featureset = '<features></features>'
```

That will let http work for server side sync for crm 9.1